# I can't start mysql in ubuntu 11.04

Tags: mysql

I downloaded following files of Oracle.com:

```
 MySQL-server-5.5.28-1.linux2.6.i386.rpm<br/>
 MySQL-client-5.5.28-1.linux2.6.i386.rpm<br/>
 MySQL-shared-5.5.28-1.linux2.6.i386.rpm<br/>
```

then with "alien -i" command installing rpm packages and when starting mysql get following error:

```
Starting MySQL<br/>
.... * The server quit without updating PID file (/var/lib/mysql/omid-desktop.pid).
```

error log:

```
121117 13:21:30 mysqld_safe Starting mysqld daemon with databases from /var/lib/mysql
121117 13:21:30 [Note] Plugin 'FEDERATED' is disabled.
/usr/sbin/mysqld: Table 'mysql.plugin' doesn't exist
121117 13:21:30 [ERROR] Can't open the mysql.plugin table. Please run mysql_upgrade to create it.
121117 13:21:30 InnoDB: The InnoDB memory heap is disabled
121117 13:21:30 InnoDB: Mutexes and rw_locks use InnoDB's own implementation
121117 13:21:30 InnoDB: Compressed tables use zlib 1.2.3
121117 13:21:30 InnoDB: Using Linux native AIO
121117 13:21:30 InnoDB: Initializing buffer pool, size = 128.0M
121117 13:21:30 InnoDB: Completed initialization of buffer pool
121117 13:21:30 InnoDB: highest supported file format is Barracuda.
121117 13:21:30  InnoDB: Waiting for the background threads to start
121117 13:21:31 InnoDB: 1.1.8 started; log sequence number 1595675
121117 13:21:31 [Note] Recovering after a crash using mysql-bin
121117 13:21:31 [Note] Starting crash recovery...
121117 13:21:31 [Note] Crash recovery finished.
121117 13:21:31 [Note] Server hostname (bind-address): '0.0.0.0'; port: 3306
121117 13:21:31 [Note]   - '0.0.0.0' resolves to '0.0.0.0';
121117 13:21:31 [Note] Server socket created on IP: '0.0.0.0'.
121117 13:21:31 [ERROR] Fatal error: Can't open and lock privilege tables: Table  'mysql.host' doesn't exist
121117 13:21:31 mysqld_safe mysqld from pid file /var/lib/mysql/omid-desktop.pid ended
121117 13:25:38 mysqld_safe Starting mysqld daemon with databases from /var/lib/mysql
121117 13:25:38 [Note] Plugin 'FEDERATED' is disabled.
/usr/sbin/mysqld: Table 'mysql.plugin' doesn't exist
121117 13:25:38 [ERROR] Can't open the mysql.plugin table. Please run mysql_upgrade to   create it.
121117 13:25:38 InnoDB: The InnoDB memory heap is disabled
121117 13:25:38 InnoDB: Mutexes and rw_locks use InnoDB's own implementation
121117 13:25:38 InnoDB: Compressed tables use zlib 1.2.3
121117 13:25:38 InnoDB: Using Linux native AIO
121117 13:25:38 InnoDB: Initializing buffer pool, size = 128.0M
121117 13:25:38 InnoDB: Completed initialization of buffer pool
121117 13:25:38 InnoDB: highest supported file format is Barracuda.
121117 13:25:38  InnoDB: Waiting for the background threads to start
121117 13:25:39 InnoDB: 1.1.8 started; log sequence number 1595675
/usr/sbin/mysqld: Too many arguments (first extra is 'start').
Use --verbose --help to get a list of available options
121117 13:25:39 [ERROR] Aborting

121117 13:25:39  InnoDB: Starting shutdown...
121117 13:25:40  InnoDB: Shutdown completed; log sequence number 1595675
121117 13:25:40 [Note] /usr/sbin/mysqld: Shutdown complete
```

Comment: Why are you installing rpm packages in Ubuntu? Wouldn't it be easier for you to just `sudo apt-get install mysql-client mysql-server`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Converting between package formats intended for different distributions is not a perfect process (and never will be), you really should try to use Ubuntu (or at least Debian) packages. Sometimes if you need a newer version than exists in the Ubuntu repositories you can find it in Debian [testing](http://packages.debian.org/search?keywords=mysql&searchon=names&suite=testing&section=all), [unstable](http://packages.debian.org/search?keywords=mysql&searchon=names&suite=unstable&section=all) or even [experimental](http://packages.debian.org/search?keywords=mysql&searchon=names&suite=experimental&section=all) series.

But first thing I'd try is:

```
sudo chown -R mysql:mysql /var/lib/mysql
```